# I want to add reactstrap and bootstrap to React Web Coding

Tags: reactjs

I want to add reactstrap and bootstrap to React Web Coding.
In a new terminal window I typed `npm install reactstrap` and `npm install bootstrap`
and I get this error:

```
C:\reactcourse\intro>npm install reactstrap
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependenc
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-libra
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/reac
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2"
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/re
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^11.2.
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the roo
npm ERR!     1 more (reactstrap)
npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, reactstr
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules
npm ERR!   react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactst
npm ERR!   node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!     reactstrap@"*" from the root pro
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --lega
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentia
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\emrec\AppData\Local\npm

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be fo
npm ERR!     C:\Users\emrec\AppData\Local\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the fact that `reactstrap` uses the v1 of `react-popper` which is not compatible with the version of `react` you use (`@^17.0.1`).

You should either consider using a minor version of react or as I would advise you, consider using another UI component library like `material` or another more "actual" UI lib.